# In general, what's the difference between NSTextAttachment(image:) and NSTextAttachment() + setting .image?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I found that there are two ways to create an `NSTextAttachment` of an image:

```
// Way 1:
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "...")

// Way 2:
let attachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(named: "...")!)
```

I thought these two ways are totally the same, until I did it with SF Symbols' images:

```
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = UIImage(systemName: "photo")!

let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "1: Press the ")
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment))
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " button"))
textview.attributedText = fullString
```

produces:

[image]

whereas:

```
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "photo")!)

let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "1: Press the ")
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment))
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " button"))
textview.attributedText = fullString
```

produces:

[image]

I thought maybe way 2 "preserves colours" or something like that, but if I use my own image, both ways produce the same result.

Both of their documentations ([1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachment/1508378-image), [2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachment/3327290-init)) don't say anything about how they are different. Both seems to say the same thing...

So what does `NSTextAttachment(image:)` do, that `.image = ...` doesn't? Or, what does `.image = ...` do, that `NSTextAttachment(image:)` doesn't? Are there other images (other than SF symbol images) that I can see a difference?

<sub>I'm running this on Xcode 11.0 and iOS 13.0, so it might be a bug of a non-latest version of iOS?</sub>

Comment: I just checked thi on Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13.3 and it gives me the same results as way 1.  It must be a bug in iOS 13.0

Comment: @BhargavR Hmm... I ran the binary compiled with Xcode 11.0 on my iOS 13.3.1 phone and I still see the blue image. Probably an Xcode thing then. At least now I know people won't see different things on different iOS versions.

Comment: Interesting, maybe there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041458/how-to-set-color-of-templated-image-in-nstextattachment ?

Comment: @Larme That question does indeed seem to be somewhat related... Another discovery I made was that the blue color produced by Way 2 actually comes from `tintColor` of the text view. If I change the tint color to red, then Way 2 produces a red image. I feel like `.alwaysTemplated` is probably one closer to the answer, but still doesn't explain why it doesn't do it to non SF symbols images.